# Given a Distance Matrix, How to bound the corresponding points?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, graph-theory, metric-spaces

Let $D$ be a given [Euclidean Distance Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix), where the entries are the non-squared distances.

The [Gram Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the corresponding points can be computed as follows :
$$G = \frac{1}{2} (D_{0i}^2 + D_{0j}^2 - D_{ij}^2)$$

The embedding dimension is then $k = \operatorname{rank}G$.

Then, from the eigen-decomposition $G = OSO^T$ we can build the matrix $X = O\sqrt S$.

Another way to proceed is to compute :

$$F = -\frac{1}{2} (I - \mathbf{e}.\mathbf{x}^T).D.(I-\mathbf{x}.\mathbf{e}^T)$$
where $\mathbf{e}$ is the vector $(1,1,....,1)$ and $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{e} = 1$ (one can simply take $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{e}/n$). Then the matrix of coordinates is given by the decomposition $F = X^TX$. Again, $k= \operatorname{rank}F$.

Removing the $n-k$ null columns of $X$ we obtain the coordinates of the set of points described by $D$, in $k$-dimensional Euclidean space (**up to an orthogonal transformation**).

## Question

Is it possible to exhibit some constraints over $D$, or over $F$ or $G$, as to bound the corresponding vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ inside the hypercube $[-L,L]^k$ ?

*Clarification* : I am looking for something like : If $G_{ij} \leq r$ then we will have $x_i \in [-f(r),f(r)]^d$ for some known function $f$.

Comment: I dont understand the question :(....

Comment: @hyprfrcb What exactly you do not understand ?

Comment: You have a $D$ matrix (ok) and then you are calculating it for $de=I-e\cdot x^T$(why?), this is not the Gramian of $x$ but for $de$ (why?), $x$ satisfy $x^Te=1$ (so?), the range is $k$ (ok), now you want a constraint (of what?) to bound the image of $D$, inside an hypercube (the spanned space inside an hypercube? or the base of the spanned space? what is $L$?)

Comment: $G$ is the Gramian of $X$ when $D_{ij} = ||x_i - x_j||^2$ (see the paper by (J.C. Gower 'Properties of Euclidean an non-Euclidean Distance Matrices')[http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379585901879] ). What I want is a constraint over $D$ that would bound the vectors $x_i$ inside a hypercube of side $2L$ in the Euclidean space of dimension $k$, here $L$ is a real finite number.
I added another way to compute the Gramian Matrix of $X$ in the post.

Comment: So why are you taking it from $I$??, why not simply $x^TDx$??. And why not a sphere but a cube?? Why not a unit cube??

Comment: @hyprfrcb See the post, I've edited it for clarity. The reasons of why this works is not the question here, pleqse see the paper by Gower for an extensive derivation of the results.
The reason I want to bound the point coordinates in a hypercube of side $2L$ are not for discussion here, it is my question, that's all :)

(Bound the points in a hypersphere is trivial)

Comment: More answerable would be to constraint the diatance points into a cube!. And i dont see both those expressions as equivalent!! The question is turning unanswerable

Comment: I see several questions: 1. How the expressions are the point distances (could be simplified), 2. How to find a closed solution for constraining into a cube (could be solved), 3. The orthogonal transformation (this can be anything). I am still unclear, which kind of solution do you want?

Comment: Let's assume the matrix $D$ is Euclidean i.e. it represents a set of points, so 1. is assumed. The question is how to bound the points inside a hypercube ***up to an orthogonal transformation*** from their distance matrix. You can see it as : how to bound the points inside a rotation/translation of the hypercube.

Comment: An answerable question would be: Let be $x$ a matrix column of vectors, with $G=x'Dx$. Let be the eigen descomposition of $G=OSO'$ and $y=O\sqrt S$. Is there any condition $Ax\le b$ making $y_{ij} \le 1$?

Comment: @hyprfrcb As far as I know, the matrix $G$ you've defined is not the Gramian matrix of the points described by the distance matrix $D$, so this formulation does not work (Otherwise prove it?) See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix for how to recover the Gramian matrix.