# Finding the coordinates of points from Geometry matrix

Tags: geometry, machine-learning

I know this question has been asked before, so please do not asign it as a duplicated question.

This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix) is similar question but it is not useful for my case.

I tried to understand the [EAST Module](https://github.com/argman/EAST). They predicted the score map and geometry map. Where the score map is binary classification, and geometry map is consist of the five channels. the first four channels are  the points distances from the top, right, bottom, and left. the last channel is the angle rotation.

I want to understand mathematically, how they return the coordinates from distances matrix (geometry map) in the [restore_rectangle_rbox](https://github.com/argman/EAST/blob/master/icdar.py) Function

Also, can anyone give me a simple and good resources for this issue?.