# How to get positional coordinates from distance matrix? (follow-up on previous question)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, python

I have a distance matrix `D_ij`. I would like to compute the positional coordinates that yield this given distance matrix. I browsed the stack exchange forums and [came across this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156161/finding-the-coordinates-of-points-from-distance-matrix/423898#423898); however, I do not understand something and do not have sufficient reputation to comment on the post.

Assuming `i` and `j` represent rows and columns respectively, computing `M_ij` is straight-forward. I want to retrieve coordinates `X`, which in turn requires using `S` and `U`. What are `S` and `U` in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix